# After creating a JSON string, how do I retrieve data from it?

Tags: javascript, json

I'm having trouble getting data that I've put into a JSON string in javascript. I first add my values to a JSON object and then I stringify it. I'm not sure I understand why I can't get a value from it. All I see is 'undefined' in the alert.

http://codepen.io/jimmykup/pen/wjJst

```
var jsonObj = [];

var name = "1stname";
var url = "firsturl";

item = {}
item ["name"] = name;
item ["url"] = url;

jsonObj.push(item);

var jsonString = JSON.stringify(jsonObj);

alert (jsonString.url);
```

I am converting my object to a string because I will be transferring that text somewhere and only THEN do I need to access the values.

Comment: [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) is the dual of `JSON.stringify`.  It takes a string and returns a separately allocated value.

Comment: Why are you creating a JSON string when you have the original object? JSON is used for serializing when you transfer an object over the network.

Comment: Stringify an object when you need to transfer it elsewhere as text. To interact with it prior to stringify access it directly (`x = item ["url"]`) to access it wherever the *string* is received convert it back to an object with `JSON.parse`

Comment: I didn't understood what you want to achieve ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `JSON.parse()` to convert a JSON string back into an object. Also, since your object is an array, you need to index it before accessing the `url` property.

```
var newObj = JSON.parse(jsonString);
alert (newObj[0].url);
```

Comment: In this case, he just should never have used `jsonString = JSON.stringify(jsonObj);`

Comment: Thank you. I don't know why I thought I could get the data from the string. Brain fart I suppose.